# How to accept programmatically a ringing call in Android 8.0?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Is it possible to answer a ringing call programmatically on Android 8.0 (without human interaction) ? I used some methods from older releases, but they didn't work (for example the ITelephony Interface solution)...

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried looking it up? What code do you already have?

This method worked for me:

```
if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
   IncomingActivity incomingActivity = IncomingActivity.this;
   new Thread(new C1736O(incomingActivity)).start();
} else if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
   IncomingActivity incomingActivity2 = IncomingActivity.this;
   new Thread(new C1735LN(incomingActivity2)).start();
} else {
   Intent i= new Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON");
   i.putExtra("android.intent.extra.KEY_EVENT", new KeyEvent(0, 79));

   IncomingActivity.this.sendOrderedBroadcast(i, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
   Intent i2= new Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON");
   i2.putExtra("android.intent.extra.KEY_EVENT", new KeyEvent(1, 79));

   IncomingActivity.this.sendOrderedBroadcast(i2, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
}
```

Comment: I tried these methods too https://inneka.com/programming/android/end-call-in-android-programmatically/